# HTTP Server cannot send file to Clients on Chrome, IE is ok

Tags: java, httpserver

I am using Java SE (system constraint).

```
    private void sendResponse(byte [] response, HttpExchange httpExchange){
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="code">
        if(response != null && response.length > 0 && httpExchange != null){
            try{
                OutputStream outputStream = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
                httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(0, response.length);
                outputStream.write(response);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                httpExchange.getRequestBody().close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(Misc.getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }
        //</editor-fold>
    }
```

Using the above code to send a response, the server is able to do everything.. EXCEPT let users on Chrome download stuff like zip, jars, etc. Java Web deployments are fine, though.

How do I fix this problem?

Regards.

Comment: 0 isn't a valid HTTP response code. Try sending 200 instead.

Comment: well, that solved it quickly. THANKS FOR THE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided by Blender, whoever cares about this should thumb him up. Change HTTP code from 0 to 200, and everything will work.